# Google Earth Engine (GEE): Using closing filter (Focal_max) on masked image

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter, masking

I am working on a script for flood mapping. I have created a watermask and now need to use two morphological filters with a window of 3x3 pixels, first a dilation filter that enlarges the water mask boundaries and second an erosion removing small holes. However, I get an all blue image when using the following operation:

```
// Define area of interest (AOI) from feature collection 'regions'

var hue = regions.filter(
  ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Thua Thien - Hue'));
Map.addLayer(hue, {color: 'yellow'}, 'Hue AdmBoundaries',0, 1);

//Find flood images in the flood period 

var FloodD = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S1_GRD")
.filterBounds(hue)
.filterDate ('2020-10-05', '2020-11-20')
.filterMetadata('instrumentMode', 'equals', 'IW')
.filterMetadata ('orbitProperties_pass', 'equals', 'DESCENDING');


//Create Flood Images over time

var Flood1 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S1_GRD")
.filterBounds(hue)
.filterDate ('2020-10-08', '2020-10-12')
.filterMetadata('instrumentMode', 'equals', 'IW')
.filterMetadata ('orbitProperties_pass', 'equals', 'DESCENDING')
.mosaic()
.clip(hue);

//set visualisation parameters
var vis = {min:-32, max:0, bands:['VH'], opacity:1.0
};

//display Flood image on the map
Map.centerObject (Flood1, 10);
Map.addLayer (Flood1, vis,'Flood Image 10.10.2020', 0, 1 );


//Create Image collection as Reference for the period before the flooding

var Ref = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S1_GRD")
.filterBounds(hue)
.filterDate ('2020-03-01', '2020-09-01')
.filterMetadata('orbitProperties_pass', 'equals', 'DESCENDING')
.filterMetadata('instrumentMode', 'equals', 'IW');

print (Ref.size(), 'Reference Collection Count');
print (Ref, 'Reference Collection');

//display on the map
Map.centerObject (hue, 10);
Map.addLayer (Ref, vis,'Ref Images', 0, 1);

//PART2 - EXAMPLE CALCULATION FOR FLOOD IMAGE 1

//merge the image collections for the layer reference+flood (Reference & Flood)

var mergedColle = Ref.merge(Flood1);

Map.addLayer (mergedColle, vis, 'Flood + Reference 1', 0, 1);

//creating bands for NDFI
var mean = Ref.select('VH').mean().clip(hue);
var min = mergedColle.select('VH').min().clip(hue);

print (mean, 'mean of Reference');
print (min, 'minimum of merged Collection 1');

//add these bands to map and inspect

Map.addLayer(mean, vis, 'mean 1', 0, 1);
Map.addLayer(min, vis, 'min 1', 0, 1);

//calculate NDFI

var ndfi = (mean.subtract(min).divide(mean.add(min)).rename(['ndfi']));
print (ndfi, 'NDFI');

Map.addLayer(ndfi, {min:-0.4, max: 0.01, bands: ['ndfi'], gamma: 0.15}, 'NDFI 1', 0, 1);

//find threshold according to Cian et al. (2018)

//Threshold for masking flood


// Mean and standard deviation reducers.
var meanReducer = ee.Reducer.mean();
var stdReducer = ee.Reducer.stdDev();

// Use the reducer to get the mean and SD of the image.
var meanNDFI = ee.Number(ndfi.reduceRegion({
  reducer: meanReducer,
  bestEffort: true,
  scale: 10,
  geometry: hue,
}).get('ndfi'));

var stdDevNDFI = ee.Number(ndfi.reduceRegion({
  reducer: stdReducer,
  bestEffort: true,
  scale: 10,
  geometry: hue,
}).get('ndfi'));

print(meanNDFI, 'mean NDFI 1', stdDevNDFI, 'std Deviation NDFI 1'); 

var th = (meanNDFI.subtract(stdDevNDFI.multiply(0.2)));
print (th, 'threshold NDFI 1');

var Flood_thres = ndfi.lt(th);
print (Flood_thres, 'flood_thres');

Map.addLayer (Flood_thres.updateMask(Flood_thres), {palette:"0000FF"},
'Flood Extent 10.10.', 0);

*this is the relevant part:*
// Force projection of 10 meters/pixel, which is the native Sentinel-1 resolution.
var SCALE = 10;

// Select the classification band of interest.
var image2 = Flood_thres.select(['ndfi']).lt(th);
// Reproject to WGS84 to force the image to be reprojected on load.
// This is just for display purposes, to visualize the input to
// the following operations.  The next reproject is sufficient
// to force the computation to occur at native scale.
var image3 = image2.reproject('EPSG:4326', null, SCALE);

// Use erosion and dilation to get rid of small islands.
var image5 = image4.focal_max().focal_min();
// Reproject to force the operations to be performed at SCALE.
var image6 = image5.reproject('EPSG:4326', null, SCALE);
```

I have this code from the Landcover Cleanup example in google developers.

Can someone help?